# Custom UITableViewCell not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm trying to create and use a custom UITableView cell in my table view, but it's acting funky.  When I run the app the table looks like this:

[image]

This is correct.  However, when I select a cell, the view shifts to this:

[image]

As far as I can tell, it seems after selecting the cell that the cell view shifts to a default UITableViewCell layout with my star image behind it...  If I proceed to select each cell I get this:

[image]

As you can see, the star image (my custom view) only shows up (albeit screwy) when I select the cell again.

I've gone through [Apple's tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) when trying to make the custom cell so I know I'm doing everything I'm supposed to, but nobody else on StackOverflow has had a similar problem...

Here is the code for my project.

TableView Controller Header

```
//
//  TableViewController.h
//  CustomCell
//
//  Created by Jordan Gardner on 1/29/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Jordan Gardner. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

TableView Controller Implementation

```
//
//  TableViewController.m
//  CustomCell
//
//  Created by Jordan Gardner on 1/29/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Jordan Gardner. All rights reserved.
//

#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController

#pragma mark - Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    //  Configure cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %@", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_folder.png"];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

CustomCell Header

```
//
//  CustomCell.h
//  CustomCell
//
//  Created by Jordan Gardner on 1/29/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Jordan Gardner. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *favoriteButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;

@end
```

CustomCell implementation

```
//
//  CustomCell.m
//  CustomCell
//
//  Created by Jordan Gardner on 1/29/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Jordan Gardner. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

So, any suggestions as to how I can prevent the views from acting so screwy would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you different names for your elements in the custom cell, rather than using the default `textLabel` and `imageView`. At times, they conflict.

Comment: And the money goes to @n00bProgrammer

Comment: @n00bProgrammer might be right, I would first change textLabel to something else.  Second, are you using autolayout?  If so check that you do not have an ambiguous layout.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer was right.  It's working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the question comments by @n00bProgrammer, I was using names like `textLabel` and `imageView` that were conflicting with the default values and therefore causing the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **solution**.All you need to do is add the below code in *cellForRowAtIndexPath*.

```
cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds
cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleLeftMargin,
                                     .FlexibleWidth,
                                     .FlexibleRightMargin,
                                     .FlexibleTopMargin,
                                     .FlexibleHeight,
                                     .FlexibleBottomMargin]
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question comments, @n00bProgrammer correctly pointed out that I was using default names – `textLabel` and `imageView` – which was causing the unusual behavior.

Answer (score -1):

- layout the custom cell on your UItableview
- select the custom cell and select the identity inspector. Add the custom UitableViewCell class for the new cell.
- Select the attributes inspector and add the unique identifier as per your code.
- Make the connections with the controls on the cell to the custom class.
- when loading the tableview, access the controls on the custom cell per below.

  ```
  MSCMoreOptionTableViewCell *cell = (MSCMoreOptionTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];


  if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[MSCMoreOptionTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                          reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
  }


  cell.label_whatever.text = @"whatever";
  ```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but you may have read the question too quickly... I did all that already.